# C++ Sort Class Type Vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a struct named Recipes.h and a vector called `vector<Recipes> recipes`. The vector contains 1 int, and 2 strings in each element (a string chef name and a string called instructions). However I want to sort the whole vector ONLY by the string chef_name. I tried doing something like this

```
sort(recipes.begin(),recipes.end(),compare);
bool Menu::compare(const recipes* lhs, const recipes* rhs)
```

But it says recipes is not a type name. How do I go about sorting this vector?

Comment: Please show more code and use the right terminology. I'm pretty sure your `struct` isn't called `Recipes.h` and your `vector` isn't called `vector recipes`.

Comment: Post complete, minimal code, including your class definition and your usage.

Comment: the full name of `compare` is `Menu::compare`...

Comment: Please don't get into the habit of naming classes and variables the same with only a single capitalized letter difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the very short snip of code you posted, it can be seen that you use `recipes` first as an object and then as a type. Your comparison function probably wants as parameters `Recipes > const&` instead. Note that if the operation does not depend on the `Menu` class it would be better to declare this function as a `static` member function.

The function signature should be:

```
static bool Menu::compare(const Recipes& lhs, const Recipes& rhs)
```

and you would then use it like this:

```
sort(recipes.begin(),recipes.end(),compare); ...or...
sort(recipes.begin(),recipes.end(),&Menu::compare);
```

Both last statements are the same, I think the later is more explicit about `compare`.

Comment: I would expect the signature to be `static bool Menu::compare(const Recipes& lhs, const Recipes& rhs)`

Comment: @Mooing Duck: I somehow forgot this was about a comparison function object. Fixed.